# Android How to Open Facebook App?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [launch facebook app from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app)

I am doing one android project, In that project i need to get Facebook User Details like UserId,AccessToken.

Done Facebook Integration using Fcebook SDK.

Now, Facebook Released **URL SCHEME** to open facebook application and get user details.

I'm Done like this,

```
long longFacebookUid = Long.parseLong(facebookUid);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_user_id", facebookUid);
this.startActivity(intent);
return;
```

In this code Called Facebook Application, After that i don't no How to get userId  and Token.

Thanks.

Comment: See this accepted answer.. Nicely explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068866/android-how-to-get-user-details-after-successful-login-through-facebook/13069081#13069081

Comment: That is Facebook SDK that is working fine for me. i need to open facebook app and get user details.

Comment: you want me to parse the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside  URL SCHEME, using the SDK based function is more simple.But it may not be the answer you want.

Remarks: The following information is based on facebook-android SDK 2.0(3.0 is avaliable now)

After running the authorize function (Login Part)(The following is sample code in facebook document)

```
 facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }
```

In order to get the access token, just run the following function in SDK 2.0

```
String access_token=facebook.getAccessToken();
```

For the userID

```
public String GetUserID(){
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "id");
    String resp= "";
    try {
        resp = facebook.request("me", params, "GET");//call the request function in SDK 2.0, using graph api
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    try{
        resp = new JSONObject(resp).getString("id");
    }catch(JSONException e1){
    }
    }
    return resp;
};
```

I think these are the most simply way to get the result, but not using the URL SCHEME.

I hope it can help you.