# How to get Facebook details after log-in in android?

Tags: android, facebook

> I am building an android application where user log-in in Facebook
>   page.
>
> Here is the code -

```
package loginpck;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView btnfb;
// Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "appid";

// Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

btnfb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnfacebook);

btnfb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loginToFacebook();
    }
   });

   }

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] mImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.chiang_mai,
    R.drawable.himeji,
    R.drawable.petronas_twin_tower,
    R.drawable.ulm
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return mImages.length;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((ImageView) object);
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  Context context = MainActivity.this;
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
      R.dimen.padding_medium);
  imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
  imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}

public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);


    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
} 
}
```

> When I move to other Activity I need to toast the user details like
>   name, image and profile detail's.
>
> How can I get the user detail's ?
>
> Here is second activity :

```
public class BallDropActivity extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.balldroplayout);


}   
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068866/how-to-get-user-details-after-successful-login-through-facebook?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

> first create your project and get **app. id** then pass the cod in your code like this

```
public static final String mAPP_ID = "Your APP ID";
    Facebook mFacebook= new Facebook(mAPP_ID); 
and setOnClickListener on your button in On Create()
 // facebook login button click event
 try{           
        //mFacebook.logout(LoginActivity.this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.loginPageFaceBookButton)).setOnClickListener(loginButtonListener);

        SessionStore.restore(mFacebook,LoginPage.this);         

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this,"Exception"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}

// loginButtonListener
    //----------------------------------------------

    private OnClickListener loginButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
            if(!mFacebook.isSessionValid() )
            {   
                mFacebook.authorize(LoginPage.this, new String[] {"publish_stream","email","user_groups","read_stream","user_about_me","offline_access"},Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
            }
            else
            {
                try 
                {

                    JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
                    facebookID = json.getString("id");
                    facebookEmail = json.getString("email");
                    faceBooklastName=json.getString("last_name");
                    faceBookFirstName=json.getString("first_name");


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    //Toast.makeText( LoginActivity.this,"Exception FB "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch( FacebookError error )
                {
                    Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }}; 
  //onActivityResult
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


// DialogListener CLASS STATRT HERE.

 public final class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener
    {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values)
        {
            try 
            {
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
                facebookID = json.getString("id");
                facebookEmail = json.getString("email");
                SessionStore.save(mFacebook, LoginPage.this); Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this,"facebookID :"+facebookID+" \n "+"facebookEmail : "+facebookEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch( Exception error ) 
            {
                Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch( FacebookError error )
            {
                Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.1"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onError(DialogError error) {
            Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.2"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 

        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText( LoginPage.this, "Something went wrong. Please try again.3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        /******  Facebook Login End  *******/

    }
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64291/feel-free for more query u may come to this room