# How to get User's information after logging in Facebook app and authorized your app? [Android]

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using [this](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidFacebook/) for my `Facebook` log-in and sharing. I'm wondering if instead of opening a `WebView` that displays the log-in with `Facebook`is there a way when a User have already installed a `Facebook app` instead of opening the `WebView` it will opens the `Facebook app`? And when the User is already log-in in the `Facebook App` it will gets its credentials and log-in automatically in my `app`? I can't seem to find how to do this.

**Edit**

I found out that my `activityCode` always return -1 instead of >= 0 that's why it always open the `WebView` instead of the app. And also found out that I need to enabled the `Single Sign-On`, I enabled the Single Sign-On but it still doesn't open the `facebook app`. Maybe it is because of  `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH` that always returns `-1`. I'm wondering if there is a default value instead of using `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH`.

In solution on the `FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH` I used code below:

Instead of using

```
facebook.authorize(this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS,
            Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

I used

```
facebook.authorize(this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
```

where in my `Facebook.java`

```
 public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        final DialogListener listener) {
    authorize(activity, permissions, DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE, listener);
}
```

Also it detects now if there is an `Facebook app` installed or not, but when there is an `Facebook app` installed it still doesn't display/open in `Facebook app`, it just load and goes back to my Activity nothing happens.

**Update**

I tried to log in without a user log-in in the `Facebook app` and that user is still not authorized to use my app, it opens the `Facebook app` log-in screen but after authorizing it, it doesn't get my log-in informations.

Here's my code in `Facebook.java` it same as it is

```
private boolean startSingleSignOn(Activity activity, String applicationId,
        String[] permissions, int activityCode) {
    boolean didSucceed = true;
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana",
            "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");
    intent.putExtra("client_id", applicationId);
    if (permissions.length > 0) {
        intent.putExtra("scope", TextUtils.join(",", permissions));
    }

    // Verify that the application whose package name is
    // com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth
    // has the expected FB app signature.
    if (!validateActivityIntent(activity, intent)) {
        return false;
    }

    mAuthActivity = activity;
    mAuthPermissions = permissions;
    mAuthActivityCode = activityCode;
    try {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, activityCode);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        didSucceed = false;
    }

    return didSucceed;
}
```

In my activity that calls the authorizing and handles what to do after authorizing here's my code

```
private void setFacebookConnection() {
```

//        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

```
    facebook = new Facebook(Constants.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    facebookAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
```

//        facebook.authorize(MerchantDetailsActivity.this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS,
//                Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());

```
    facebook.authorize(MerchantDetailsActivity.this, Constants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());

}

private class LoginDialogListener implements Facebook.DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

        String token = facebook.getAccessToken();
        long token_expires = facebook.getAccessExpires();
        Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
        Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);

        facebookSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        facebookSharedPreferences.edit()
                .putLong(Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_EXPIRES, token_expires)
                .commit();
        facebookSharedPreferences.edit()
                .putString(Constants.FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN, token).commit();
        facebookAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());

        shareFBPost();
    }
```

It seems that when the user is already authorized it doesn't go inside my `LoginDialogListener`

Comment: If you implement according to Facebook's documentation, yes. However, it will still open up a WebView if the app isn't installed. It's not very hard to implement as the documentation will guide you along the way to set up.

Comment: I implement it using the link I've provided but even if the `Facebook app` is already installed it still opens the `WebView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the latest Facebook SDK instead and follow [these](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2) steps. It is important to add `onActivityResult` for Facebook login `callbackManager`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) guide you will be able to open Facebook app for login

After implementing Facebook auth, initialize Facebook SDK in your Application class or in activity which uses Facebook login

```
// initialize facebook sdk and app events logger
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Then you can use the class below to login

```
public class FacebookAuth { 
    private static FacebookAuth instance; 
    private OnLoginDataReadyListener mResponseListener; 
    public static synchronized FacebookAuth getInstance() { 
        if (instance == null) { 
            instance = new FacebookAuth(); 
        } 
        return instance; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Call if you want the user to login with his facebook account 
     * @param activity needed to initialize the Facebook LoginManager 
     * @param listener used to set the login listener 
     */ 
     public void facebookLogin(Activity activity, OnLoginDataReadyListener listener, CallbackManager callbackManager) { 
         mResponseListener = listener;
         LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
         LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() { 
            @Override 
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) { 
                getUserData(); 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onCancel() { 
                if (mResponseListener != null) { 
                    mResponseListener.onCanceled(); 
                } 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                if (mResponseListener != null) { 
                    mResponseListener.onCanceled(); 
                } 
            } 
         }); 
     } 

    /** 
     * Creates an Facebook Graph request witch will grab the user data 
     * such as name id and picture for now 
     */ 
    public void getUserData() { 
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() { 
            @Override 
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) { 
                if (mResponseListener != null) {
                    mResponseListener.onLoginDataReady(object);
                }
            } 
        }); 
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "picture.height(200).width(200),cover,location,birthday,first_name,last_name,email,gender,name"); 
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    } 

    public interface OnLoginDataReadyListener { 
        void onLoginDataReady(JSONObject facebookData); 
        void onCanceled(); 
    }
}
```

Once you've implemented the above solution, în your activity create a CallbackManager

```
CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Then in button click listener you can login your user as following

```
FacebookAuth.getInstance().facebookLogin(activity, dataReadyListener, mCallbackManager);
```

And finally in onActivityResult()

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

Hope this will help you ))

Comment: I'm having cannot resolve symbol `OnLoginDataReadyListener`

Comment: @mori this is the interface at the bottom of FacebookAuth.class

Comment: I should not call `GraphRequest` in my `onCreate` in my `Activity`?

Comment: @mori you will get user data right after login using OnLoginDataReadyListener interface